# Multiple Dateformat

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

i am task to change the dateformat according to the user's language. Currently the website runs in Chinese and English, However i am unable to change the format of the mask according to the user's language.

```
<h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
                        id="index_output_todate" value="#{msg.index_output_todate}">
</h:outputText>
<p:calendar value="#{pc_Index.w_message.am_todate_filter}"
    id="index_input_todate" styleClass="calendar" maxlength="10"
    pattern="#{pc_Index.dateDisplayFormat}" onfocus="$(this).mask('9999年99月99日');">
<p:watermark for="index_input_todate" value="#{pc_Index.watermarkDateDisplayFormat}" />
<f:convertDateTime pattern="#{pc_Index.dateDisplayFormat}" />
</p:calendar>
```

I need the date format of the mask to be 9999年99月99日 when the user login as a zh_CN user or a date format of DD/MM/YYYY for en_UK user. 
Is there a way to do this?

I had already set the locale

```
 public String getDateDisplayFormat() {  

    String locale = getUserLocale();
    String DATEFORMAT_UK = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    String DATEFORMAT_US = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    String DATEFORMAT_CN = "yyyy年MM月dd日";
    String _s = DATEFORMAT_UK;
    if(!isEmptyNull(locale) && locale.equals("en_US")) {
        _s = DATEFORMAT_US;
    }
    else if(!isEmptyNull(locale) && locale.equals("zh_CN")) {
        _s = DATEFORMAT_CN;
    }
    return _s;
}
```

**EDIT:**

HTML

```
              <h:form> <p:outputLabel for="index_output_frdate" value="#{msg.index_output_frdate}" /> 
                    <p:calendar id="index_output_frdate" value="#{pc_Index.w_message.am_todate_filter}" 
                                    styleClass="calendar" maxlength="10"
                                    pattern="#{pc_Index.dateDisplayFormat}" mask="true" />  
                    <p:watermark for="index_output_frdate" value="#{pc_Index.watermarkDateDisplayFormat}" /> </h:form>
```

Manage Bean:

```
                         if (isPageFirstLoad(JSP)) {
        _w.setIndex_viewtype("11961003");
        if (isEmptyNull(_w.getAm_todate_filter())) {
            _w.setAm_todate_filter(getTodayDate());
        }

        Date _todate = _w.getAm_todate_filter();
        Date d = _w.addDaysToDate(_todate, -7);
        _w.setAm_frdate_filter(d);
        _w.setViewNew(true);
        _w.populateAlertsMessages();
    }

    if (this.trigger_viewtype_change) {
        this.trigger_viewtype_change = false;
    }
}









     private Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getDateDisplayFormat() {
    String locale = getUserLocale(); //WARNING!! Hard-coded!!
    final String DATEFORMAT_UK = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    final String DATEFORMAT_US = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    final String DATEFORMAT_CN = "yyyy年MM月dd日";
    if(!locale.isEmpty() && locale.equals("en_US")) {
       return DATEFORMAT_US;
    }
    if(!locale.isEmpty() && locale.equals("zh_CN")) {
       return DATEFORMAT_CN;
    }
    return DATEFORMAT_UK;
}
```

Doesn't seems to have anything wrong. but the mask just doesnt seem to come out

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know what snippet of your code fails exactly. I've tried an easier example and works very well, so I recommend you debug all your involved code in this functionality.

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel for="mask" value="Mask:" />
    <p:calendar id="mask" value="#{dumpController.date}" pattern="#{dumpController.dateDisplayFormat}" mask="true" />
    <p:watermark for="mask" value="Input a date" />
</h:form>
```

Method in charge to set the date's mask:

```
private Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getDateDisplayFormat() {
    final String locale = "zh_CN"; //WARNING!! Hard-coded!!
    final String DATEFORMAT_UK = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    final String DATEFORMAT_US = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    final String DATEFORMAT_CN = "yyyy年MM月dd日";
    if(!locale.isEmpty() && locale.equals("en_US")) {
       return DATEFORMAT_US;
    }
    if(!locale.isEmpty() && locale.equals("zh_CN")) {
       return DATEFORMAT_CN;
    }
    return DATEFORMAT_UK;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The mask doesn't seems to work. Nothing seems to appear when i focus on it.

Comment: try deleting the value and it should have a blank space like this ____年__月__日

Comment: Sorry, but I don´t understand where is the problem. This behavior is the correct. The mask put underscores (_) in the places to be filled.

Comment: after many attempts i still can't get what you have over there this is what i change

        <h:form>
    <p:outputLabel for="index_input_todate" value="Mask:" />
    <p:calendar id="index_input_todate" value="#{pc_Index.w_message.am_todate_filter}" 
       pattern="#{pc_Index.dateDisplayFormat}" mask="true" />
    <p:watermark for="index_input_todate" value="#{pc_Index.watermarkDateDisplayFormat}" />
</h:form>

not sure what but something is preventing me from displaying the mask .

Comment: The xhtml code seems correct. Perhaps, the ManagedBeans are the problem. The nomenclature used by you isn't the "traditional". Please, update your question with the code's latest version including Beans' code.

Comment: Why the `value` of `p:calendar` is `pc_Index.w_message.am_todate_filter`? I've seen in your bean code the variable is called `_w`. Do you have a method called `getW_message` where you returns `_w`?

Comment: Ah, i just realize. I'm using Primefaces 3.5. so the mask featured is not included in my version.